# How to convert estimated precision to variance?

Tags: variance, estimation, data-transformation, estimators, back-transformation

I have a simple model in `INLA` (the regressor is a single `model=iid` term), which reports the precision of the hyperparameter. How to convert it to variance?

**Question #1**: Is my understanding correct that the CI can be simply converted by taking the reciprocal of the endpoints? (As reciprocal [is an](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187154/does-invertible-monotone-transformation-of-a-confidence-interval-give-you-a-conf) invertible monotone transformation.)

**Question #2**: What to do with the point estimator? This is not an MLE, thus no invariance principle applies, so, if my understanding is correct, I can't simple take its reciprocal.

Comment: I'm guessing that INLA is doing enough approximate things (finding a MAP estimator, Laplace approximation, Wald CIs, etc.) that you should just invert. If you want you could assume that the posterior of precision is Gaussian and try to calculate the mean (or mode) of $1/\tau$ (by delta method, or ...)

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you very much! Intuitively I totally understand your logic (of simply taking the reciprocal), but do you have anything written to substantiate this, that I could cite in a paper...?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Maybe you can ask on the INLA mailing list (available via the [INLA web page](http://www.r-inla.org/) ?

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the suggestion, I received an extremely quick answer from them: http://www.r-inla.org/?place=msg%2Fr-inla-discussion-group%2FdtyiObx11GY%2FMmJJrfMvCAAJ . (I don't know what is the Stackexchange policy in this case; is it enough if I leave the link here among the comments...?)

Comment: If you got a useful answer from them, you should post it (or at least the highlights) here, with appropriate attribution, as an answer. Comments are considered ephemeral, off-site links are semi-ephemeral.

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks! I followed your suggestion. (Although I accept it as a solution, I don't really want the accept it in Stackexchange sense... it'd look quite strange, as the answer is not actually mine.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the suggestion of @BenBolker, I've asked this on the R-INLA mailing list, where I received an extremely rapid and detailed [response](http://www.r-inla.org/?place=msg%2Fr-inla-discussion-group%2FdtyiObx11GY%2FMmJJrfMvCAAJ) from Håvard Rue.

Briefly, log precision should be extracted and then transformed:

```
 m <- fit$internal.marginals.hyperpar[[1]]
 m.var <- inla.tmarginal(function(x) 1/exp(x), m)
 inla.zmarginal(m.var)
```

where `fit` is the fitted model.

Again, credit goes to Håvard Rue.