# Why does this demonstration of a GLM have a confident fit so far from the truth?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

sample code:

```
set.seed(123)
n = 500
x = rnorm(n)
a = -5
b = 0.5

y = exp(a + b * x + rnorm(n))
plot(x, y, pch = 20)

m = glm(y ~ x, family = gaussian(link = "log"))

sample_coefs = MASS::mvrnorm(n = 5000, mu = m$coefficients, Sigma = vcov(m))
sample_x = seq(-4, 4, 0.05)
sample_lines = sample_coefs |> apply(1, \(pars){exp(pars[1] + sample_x * pars[2])}) |> apply(1, \(x)quantile(x, c(0.1, 0.9)))
polygon(x = c(sample_x, rev(sample_x)), y = c(sample_lines[1,], rev(sample_lines[2,])), col = rgb(1, 0, 0, 0.5))

y_true = exp(a + sample_x * b)
lines(sample_x, y_true, col = "blue", lwd = 2)
y_est = exp(m$coefficients[1] + sample_x * m$coefficients[2])
lines(sample_x, y_est, lwd = 2)

y_buffer_90 = qnorm(p = 0.9, sd = summary(m)$sigma)
lines(x = sample_x, y = m$coefficients[1] + sample_x * m$coefficients[2] + y_buffer_90)
lines(x = sample_x, y = m$coefficients[1] + sample_x * m$coefficients[2] - y_buffer_90)
```

[image: plot output]

The thick black line shows the estimated relationship. The red area shows the 80% confidence interval of the estimated relationship. The blue line shows the true relationship.

As can be seen, the truth is far from the fit. Why does this happen?

Comment: See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/575974/21054). Your simulation of the data does not correspond to the model you fit. The GLM model is $y = \exp{(a + bx)} + N(0, \sigma^2)$ or equivalently $y = N(\exp{(a + bx)}, \sigma^2)$. Try this: `y <- exp(a + b * x) + rnorm(n, 0, 0.001)` and fit the GLM again.

Comment: @COOLSerdash, spot on, thanks! If you would like to elevate your comment to an answer I will mark is as accepted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember that the GLM models the conditional mean of $Y$ and consists of three parts:

1. The conditional distribution of $Y$ (here assumed to be Gaussian)
2. The link function  (here a log-link).
3. The linear predictor.

In particular, your model is the following:
$$
\log(\operatorname{E}(Y|X)) = -5 + 0.5x
$$
Together with the conditional distribution, we have
$$
Y = \operatorname{N}(\exp{(-5 + 0.5*x)}, \sigma^2)
$$
So the correct data simulation corresponding to this model would be

```R
y = exp(a + b * x) + rnorm(n, 0, 0.001)
```

Note that I've chosen $\sigma = 0.001$ here because otherwise the model wouldn't converge for me. Additional information can be found in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/575974/21054).

Plotting the model fit and the true DGP, we now have an excellent agreement:

```R
library(visreg)

set.seed(123)
n = 500
x = rnorm(n)
a = -5
b = 0.5

y = exp(a + b * x) + rnorm(n, 0, 0.001)
plot(x, y, pch = 20)

m = glm(y ~ x, family = gaussian(link = "log"), start = c(1, 1))

visreg(m, "x", scale = "response", rug = FALSE)
points(y~x, pch = 1, cex = 0.5)
curve((\(x)(exp(a + b*x)))(x), from = min(x), to = max(x), add = TRUE, col = "red")
```

[image: GLMfit]

The two lines are barely distinguishable.

Comment: thanks for also telling me about visreg. much easier!