# Am I using emmeans correctly to look at pairwise differences after running a type III ANOVA model?

Tags: regression, anova, interaction, multiple-comparisons, lsmeans

I am looking at how the weight of female individuals is influenced by the two factors A (5 levels) and B (2 levels) using a type III ANOVA as follows:

```
model.weight<-lm(Weight~A*B, data = weight.females)
summary(model.weight)

Call:
lm(formula = Weight ~ A * B, data = weight.females)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-7.9505 -1.7445 -0.0145  1.6212  9.5101 

Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)             13.98580    0.88995  15.715  < 2e-16 ***
A2                       0.48002    1.07332   0.447  0.65522    
A3                      -1.98456    1.12156  -1.769  0.07841 .  
A4                      -3.46780    1.08996  -3.182  0.00171 ** 
A5                      -3.10400    1.54144  -2.014  0.04544 *  
B2                      19.87800    1.25858  15.794  < 2e-16 ***
A2:B2                    1.84245    1.57227   1.172  0.24272    
A3:B2                   -0.03776    1.48826  -0.025  0.97979    
A4:B2                   -1.58012    1.48997  -1.061  0.29026    
A5:B2                   -4.25423    1.88286  -2.259  0.02499 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.814 on 191 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9183,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9144 
F-statistic: 238.4 on 9 and 191 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

library(car)
Anova(model.weight, contrasts=list(topic=contr.sum, sys=contr.sum), type=3)

Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: Weight
                     Sum Sq  Df  F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)         1956.03   1 246.9705 < 2.2e-16 ***
A                    202.93   4   6.4057 7.391e-05 ***
B                   1975.67   1 249.4513 < 2.2e-16 ***
A:B                  124.31   4   3.9239  0.004376 ** 
Residuals           1512.74 191                       
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I want to examine the significant interaction more closely by doing pairwise comparisons within each factor. The code I think I should use is as follows:

```
#Within B effects of A
EMM.A.BW.F <- emmeans(model.weight, specs = ~ A|B)
EMM.A.BW.F
regrid(EMM.A.BW.F)    #convert to response scale as data was sqrt transformed
pairs(regrid(EMM.A.BW.F)) #pairwise differences on response scale
cld(regrid(EMM.A.BW.F))

#Within A effects of B
EMM.B.BW.F <- emmeans(model.weight, specs = ~ B|A)
EMM.B.BW.F
regrid(EMM.B.BW.F)    # convert to response scale as data was sqrt transformed
pairs(regrid(EMM.B.BW.F)) #pairwise differences on response scale
cld(regrid(EMM.B.BW.F))
```

In the past I have used this code following a type I ANOVA however I was wondering if this would still be appropriate following a type III ANOVA? My aim is to see if there are any significant differences between the different factor levels of one factor within each level of the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you want `regrid` in your case unless you want the marginal averaging being done on the response scale and not on the transformed scale (which you likely want because you chose it for a reason). For more details see here: https://cran.r-hub.io/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/transformations.html

Just to quote the important section (and keep reading below that section as well):

> Timing is everything
>
> Dealing with transformations in emmeans is somewhat complex, due to the large number of possibilities. But the key is understanding what happens, when. These results come from a sequence of steps. Here is what happens (and doesn’t happen) at each step:
>
> The reference grid is constructed for the log(conc) model. The fact that a log transformation is used is recorded, but nothing else is done with that information.
> The predictions on the reference grid are averaged over the four percent levels, for each source, to obtain the EMMs for source – still on the log(conc) scale.
> The standard errors and confidence intervals for these EMMs are computed – still on the log(conc) scale.
> Only now do we do back-transformation…
> The EMMs are back-transformed to the conc scale.
> The endpoints of the confidence intervals are back-transformed.
> The t tests and P values are left as-is.
> The standard errors are converted to the conc scale using the delta method. These SEs were not used in constructing the tests and confidence intervals.
>
> The model is our best guide
>
> This choice of timing is based on the idea that the model is right. In particular, the fact that the response is transformed suggests that the transformed scale is the best scale to be working with. In addition, the model specifies that the effects of source and percent are linear on the transformed scale; inasmuch as marginal averaging to obtain EMMs is a linear operation, that averaging is best done on the transformed scale. For those two good reasons, back-transforming to the response scale is delayed until the very end by default.

But keep reading here: https://cran.r-hub.io/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/transformations.html#regrid

Since you didn't provide example data I used the `CO2` data and the way I think you want the data to be analyzed:

```r
require(emmeans)
#> Loading required package: emmeans
require(multcomp)

m <- lm(log(uptake) ~ Type * Treatment, data = CO2)
```

I think you really only need this approach; inference are the same compared to the following approaches below:

```
emm <- emmeans(m, ~ Type * Treatment, type = "response")
plot(emm)
```

[image]

```r
pairs(emm)
#>  contrast                                     ratio     SE df null t.ratio
#>  Quebec nonchilled / Mississippi nonchilled   1.366 0.1498 80    1   2.840
#>  Quebec nonchilled / Quebec chilled           1.129 0.1239 80    1   1.106
#>  Quebec nonchilled / Mississippi chilled      2.201 0.2415 80    1   7.190
#>  Mississippi nonchilled / Quebec chilled      0.827 0.0907 80    1  -1.734
#>  Mississippi nonchilled / Mississippi chilled 1.612 0.1768 80    1   4.350
#>  Quebec chilled / Mississippi chilled         1.949 0.2139 80    1   6.084
#>  p.value
#>   0.0286
#>   0.6870
#>   <.0001
#>   0.3130
#>   0.0002
#>   <.0001
#> 
#> P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates 
#> Tests are performed on the log scale
cld(emm)
#>  Type        Treatment  response   SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
#>  Mississippi chilled        15.3 1.18 80     13.1     17.8  1    
#>  Mississippi nonchilled     24.6 1.91 80     21.1     28.7   2   
#>  Quebec      chilled        29.8 2.31 80     25.5     34.7   23  
#>  Quebec      nonchilled     33.6 2.61 80     28.8     39.2    3  
#> 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95 
#> Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale 
#> P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates 
#> Tests are performed on the log scale 
#> significance level used: alpha = 0.05 
#> NOTE: If two or more means share the same grouping symbol,
#>       then we cannot show them to be different.
#>       But we also did not show them to be the same.
```

This will just split the data by `Treatment` (inferences remain the same compared to first approach):

```
emm2 <- emmeans(m, ~ Type | Treatment, type = "response")
plot(emm2)
```

[image]

```r
pairs(emm2)
#> Treatment = nonchilled:
#>  contrast             ratio    SE df null t.ratio p.value
#>  Quebec / Mississippi  1.37 0.150 80    1   2.840  0.0057
#> 
#> Treatment = chilled:
#>  contrast             ratio    SE df null t.ratio p.value
#>  Quebec / Mississippi  1.95 0.214 80    1   6.084  <.0001
#> 
#> Tests are performed on the log scale
cld(emm2)
#> Treatment = nonchilled:
#>  Type        response   SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
#>  Mississippi     24.6 1.91 80     21.1     28.7  1    
#>  Quebec          33.6 2.61 80     28.8     39.2   2   
#> 
#> Treatment = chilled:
#>  Type        response   SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
#>  Mississippi     15.3 1.18 80     13.1     17.8  1    
#>  Quebec          29.8 2.31 80     25.5     34.7   2   
#> 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95 
#> Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale 
#> Tests are performed on the log scale 
#> significance level used: alpha = 0.05 
#> NOTE: If two or more means share the same grouping symbol,
#>       then we cannot show them to be different.
#>       But we also did not show them to be the same.
```

This will just split the data by `Type` (inferences remain the same compared to first approach):

```
emm3 <- emmeans(m, ~ Treatment | Type, type = "response")
plot(emm3)
```

[image]

```r
pairs(emm3)
#> Type = Quebec:
#>  contrast             ratio    SE df null t.ratio p.value
#>  nonchilled / chilled  1.13 0.124 80    1   1.106  0.2721
#> 
#> Type = Mississippi:
#>  contrast             ratio    SE df null t.ratio p.value
#>  nonchilled / chilled  1.61 0.177 80    1   4.350  <.0001
#> 
#> Tests are performed on the log scale
cld(emm3)
#> Type = Quebec:
#>  Treatment  response   SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
#>  chilled        29.8 2.31 80     25.5     34.7  1    
#>  nonchilled     33.6 2.61 80     28.8     39.2  1    
#> 
#> Type = Mississippi:
#>  Treatment  response   SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
#>  chilled        15.3 1.18 80     13.1     17.8  1    
#>  nonchilled     24.6 1.91 80     21.1     28.7   2   
#> 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95 
#> Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale 
#> Tests are performed on the log scale 
#> significance level used: alpha = 0.05 
#> NOTE: If two or more means share the same grouping symbol,
#>       then we cannot show them to be different.
#>       But we also did not show them to be the same.
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-19 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: My data was only transformed due to a violated assumption of a linear model. In this case, would back transforming at the beginning be more appropriate? Also, in the case of a binomial glm would it be best to back transform at the beginning or the end?

Comment: I would follow the **default behaviour** of emmeans and not `regrid` unless you know what you are doing (just add `type = "response"`, see my example). That is, let `emmeans` calculate and average everything on the transformed scale and then at the end do the back transformation.  Even better consider a generalized linear model with an appropriate distribution family and link function. I assume your data is right-skewed since you measure weights? Weights are continuous and strictly positive. You could also run `glm(Weight~A*B, family = Gamma(link = "log), data = weight.females)`

Comment: See also here for the difference between log-transforming the outcome variable vs log-transforming the expected value: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47840/linear-model-with-log-transformed-response-vs-generalized-linear-model-with-log